Understanding ackermann_steering_controller in ros2_control
I'm currently working on an Ackermann Steering Vehicle simulation in ROS2 with Gazebo. I'm currently trying to use the ackermann_steering_controller from ros2_control to control the steering.
However, I'm a bit confused about the control messages. The documentation mentions a /ackermann_steering_controller/reference topic of type geometry_msgs/msg/TwistStamped for controlling both linear and angular velocity.
I'd like to control the steering angle of the vehicle directly instead of using angular velocity. Is there an alternative topic with other message type to TwistStamped that the controller can accept for this purpose? If not, how do I convert a desired steering angle (θ) into the angular_velocity.z field of the TwistStamped message, and how do I specify the vehicle speed using the linear_velocity.x field?
Thank you very much for your help,
Cheers.

Piggybacking off of what @Christoph has mentioned, if you'd like to convert the desired steering angle to an angular velocity, you can do it in the following manner, IIRC:
$$ \dot\phi  = \frac{v \cdot tan(\theta)}{L} $$
where $\dot\phi$ is the desired angular velocity, $v$ is the linear velocity, $\theta$ is the desired steering angle, and $L$ is the wheelbase of the robot.

Thank you so much for your response.

The ackermann_steering_controller (or steering controller library) does not support the steering angle as input.
Why do you need that? Planning frameworks like nav2 use TwistStamped as interface. Furthermore, for bicycle/tricycle controllers this wouldn't make a lot of sense because no kinematics is needed then (why to use the steering controller then?).
If there is a use case for more users, we could add that to the controller.

I'm porting my deep learning self-driving simulation to ROS2 and Gazebo. The neural network takes a frontal camera image as input and predicts steering angle and speed commands. While I probably could use angular velocity instead, I prefer to minimize code changes for a smoother port.
